# Check how many unique sub lists in a list

Tags: python, ironpython

Hi I need to filter a list of results,
the main list is called studs and it has sublists composed of the stud type, stud level, stud gauge and stud height.
like:
|-Common Stud
|-16 Gauge
|-Level 1
|-4

I would like to retrieve a list of types.
Types would be composed of a Type, Gauge and Level
So studs with the same type should be concatenated.

I am trying

But I get the whole stud list back minus the stud Height.
This is IronPython 2.7 so I don't have all the python libraries, and the map function does not take the same arguments.

Thank you!

```
for e in studs:
    concat.append([e, L[i], G[i], H[i]])
    i+=1

for e in concat:
    a= [e[0],e[1],e[2]]
    if a in types:
        continue
    else:
        types.append(a)
```

I would like to get about 5 different results with the different types of studs in the list.
Them I will use that to create a separate list with the sum per type.

Comment: can you give an example input + output?

Comment: a= [e[0],e[1],e[2]] would be something like ["Common Stud", "16 Gauge", "Level 1"]

Comment: I cannot make anything of your example nor do i understand what your actual question is. if you would define your problem as one function, what input would that function require and what would you expect to get returned by that function?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I am creating a list of various inputs that define a structural element, a metal stud. That stud has 4 characteristics. first its type, second its Level, third its Gauge, and lastly its size. I need to filter that bit list with 10k plus studs in many different ways, but It would be nice to see how many kinds of different studs I have, so I can concatenate each stud by a "Type" and have an idea of the total length of studs per type. Hope it clear it up a bit.

Comment: Each stud is a sublist in a list with its features as described

Comment: So why is your current code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
sum(isinstance(i, list) for i in a)
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: First, thank you for your help, I am new to python, would you mind elaborating? Is this like a for in just one line?